# shortcut icon doesn't shown in IE

Tags: html, browser, favicon

when i write

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/kino/img/clapperboard-icon.ico">
```

it doesn't show an icon in IE! works fine in other browsers.
could you tell me why? thanks

Comment: Shortcut icons don't work in IE 5.

Comment: @Pekka but it show for other sites, maybe i write wrong the version of IE, maybe i try in IE6, anyway in my IE browser it doesn't show for my site, but for other sites shows.

Comment: IE5, somebody still using that?! :o

Comment: From wikipedia: "Older versions of browsers such as Internet Explorer 5 and version 6[3], Mozilla Firefox, and Netscape only recognize the favicon when the page is bookmarked, and fail to display when merely visiting the page." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: @systempuntoout no, turns out I'm mistaken, they were introduced in IE4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537656(VS.85).aspx, shortcut icons are supported in IE 5

Comment: @Yaggo aaah! That sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

favicon's are second-class-citizens in most browsers. You have to clear the cache, restart the browser, and hope it updates. Otherwise just wait and the browser will eventually update it.

You say you are testing in IE5? Please don't. No website should be testing anything older than IE7. Check out Google's Chrome Frame plugin for IE.

Comment: @Coronatus it's not important in which version i test. 
i can't understand why the other site's icons were shown, but mine wasn't. i try to clear cache and restart browser, doesn't help

Comment: It *is* important. Some browsers, specially IE <7,  have tons of compatibility problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try adding it to favorites and then refreshing the page if you don't want to do all of the other stuff (clearing the cache + restarting the browser). It might work

Answer (score 0):

If you have the page bookmarked, delete the bookmark, delete your browser cache, refresh the page, bookmark the page, refresh the page. It should appear (to disappear again later).